# 2011 doxygen or just javadoc?

Tags: java, javadoc, doxygen

Doxygen vs. Javadoc has been asked before but its 2011 and I wanted some new opinions on this. Please share your experiences.  I need it for large api with lots of areas to publish or not publish depending on many factors.  Some class I want to publish everything others less so I need granular control over this.  Anyway I also want overall comparison and recent experience with doxygen.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

JavaDoc, historically doxygen is used in situations where a language does not have a decent doc facility, e.g. C++.

Also, I'm not sure if going doxygen, you get native support for Maven.

It also boils down to your targeted user demographic, are they going to be more ascustomised with doxygen or javadoc style and grammar?

Comment: To sum up, if you're developing in Java use JavaDoc and Doxygen for C/C++.